# [flash]Using the same variable names for another scene

Tags: flash, scope, scene

i'm new to AS3 programming.
I'm currently making a game where i'll have various game levels, each level being a different scene.
I've created the 1st level, but when i copied the scene to make the 2nd level, and consequently, used the same variable names as the other scene, the redefintion of the variables conflicts .
Isn't there a way that I tell the program to not go get the variables from the other scene, so it doesn't conflict redefining them?
Need quick help please, as this is a school project and I'm running short on time.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I never search about it but you probably cant. When you create a function on the first scene, you can use it on scene 2. Just try to create functions and use them on scene 2 so you dont get any conflicts error. :)